# JSF print screen like capture

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am generating some linecharts via JSF (Primefaces).

So charts are accessible and generated nicely via accessing in any browser.

However i need to send those charts via email to certain persons cause they do not want to click on a link so this should be automated.

Is there a way to generate an image out of what the JSF is rendering ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Charts are canvas based and can be exported as static images with client side api.

Take a look here:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chartExport.jsf

Comment: I think OP wants to make it programatically, but good call on that component.

Comment: Indeed ...now i think maybe i will use JFree chart ...to generate a gif which i can put it on the web page as well to send it via email

Answer (score 1):

Primefaces use [Javascript Libraries](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/trunk/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/charts/charts.js?r=4514) to render the charts. You would have to process the browser output before sending the email.

(Also, lazy managers)

You would have to dig into the Java Image API (not JSF) in order to plot the graph (from the raw data) into an image if you want the JVM to send the email.

If you want to just automate the process in your machine to send the emails (so you can send the emails in one click instead of doing it all manually, be mindful of this caveat:

[image: http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/automation.png]

You would have to generate a custom page with print CSS and your email layout, then use a browser plugin that sends the email on a click.

Comment: Funny but this one can save me some time :)